# Android - How would one fix a java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException Error: Index: 0, Size: 0

Tags: java, android, sqlite, arraylist

I need help with the following situation on an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` error. I have two classes, one is a database class which extends `SQLiteOpenHelper` and the other compares the value queried from the database class with some selection made on a spinner.

So, in the database class, I have two methods that does the database query: `getInventory()` and `getStock()`.

The `getInventory()` method first queries db then adds cursor values to the arraylist `checkInventory`. And then `getStock()` sets a return method for the arraylist.

```
List<String> checkInventory = new ArrayList<>();

public void getInventory(int primaryKey) {

    // Select All Query
    String selectQuery = "Select * FROM " + TABLE_PRODUCT + " WHERE " + PRODUCER_FK + " =  \"" + primaryKey + "\"";
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
    cursor.moveToFirst();

    while (cursor.isAfterLast() == false) {
        String productName = cursor.getString(1);
        String productQuantity = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(3));
        String productPrice = String.valueOf(cursor.getInt(2));

        checkInventory.add(productName);
        checkInventory.add(productQuantity);
        checkInventory.add(productPrice);

        cursor.moveToNext();
    }
}
    public String getStock(int pos) {
        return checkInventory.get(pos);
    }
```

Then in the `ProductInventory` class are two spinners: the `producer` and `product` spinners. I want to compare the value on the `product` spinner to the `productName` that is stored in the `checkInventory` arraylist from database class, on button click. If the values match, then the product price, product quantity together with the value of producer and product spinners should be displayed in an xml file. Here is the class:

```
// Adding click listener to Get button.
public void addListenerOnGet() {
    getBtn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(View v) {

            // database handler
            FISP_SQLiteDB db = new FISP_SQLiteDB(getApplicationContext());

            String name = db.getStock(0);
            String quantity = db.getStock(1);
            String price = db.getStock(2);

            if (name==product.getSelectedItem()){
                Intent i = new Intent(ProductInventory.this, Product_Details.class);
                i.putExtra("ProducerValue", producer.getSelectedItem().toString());
                i.putExtra("ProductValue", product.getSelectedItem().toString());
                i.putExtra("ProducerPrice", price);
                i.putExtra("ProductDetails", quantity);

                startActivity(i);
            }
        }
    });
}
```

Of course there is another class that does the setting of text on the xml and so forth. However, when I run the app, I am getting an exception: `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0.` The error is pointing to the database class.

```
public String getStock(int pos) {
        return checkInventory.get(pos);
    }
```

and to this in the other class

```
String name = db.getStock(0);
String quantity = db.getStock(1);
String price = db.getStock(2);
```

I am new to android development, and clearly there is something I am doing wrong, so is there a better approach to this? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: why need `cursor.isAfterLast() == false`?

Comment: hey John, cursor.isAfterLast() == false to prevent an infinte loop. Then moveToNext will iterate over all rows in the cursor but I may be wrong perhaps

Answer (score 3):

You forgot to call getInventory method so the checkInventory list is empty.

Comment: more like 

ArrayList<String> checkInventory = db.getInventory(primaryKey); ??

Would that be enough?

Comment: Your getInventory method does not have any return value. You probably should call it just as 'db.getInventory(primaryKey);'

Comment: interesting, am not getting the error anymore but my getButton is no longer working, its clickable but unresponsive, am I missing something, yet again?

Comment: So don't be afraid, put a breakpoint in the onclick handler and start application in the debuggin mode. You should learn how to step debug your application. It's really handy skill.

Comment: lol @Josef, that sounds like Greek to me, but let me try it first, i really want to learn

Comment: Good place to start learning greek is over there https://developer.android.com/studio/debug/index.html .)

Comment: alright, I will check it out, its 5.14PM in this part of the world, knock off time. Later

Comment: hey @Josef, thank you so much. My button is working fine now, no more errors